# Finding unique elements of a MATLAB cell array when elements are like '(p,q)'

Tags: matlab, unique, cell-array

I have a **MATLAB** cell array like this:

```
a = {'(q0, q1)' '(q2, q3)' '(q1, q0)' '(q4, q5)'};
```

`'(q0, q1)'` and `'(q1, q0)'` are indifferent in my application, So I want to eliminate one of them. What is the best way in your opinion?

Comment: What is your measure for best? Fastest? Shortest?

Comment: @NickyMattsson Least lines of code, but any solution is acceptable at this stage.

Comment: Are your tupels really char arrays, i.e. `(qx, qy)` is a char array of lenght 8? Just wanted to be sure beforehand.

Comment: @HansHirse Yes they are, but they may vary in size depending to name of nodes, eg `(q12, q3)` is of length 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [HansHirse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54913414/52738) and I are [golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). :)

I went the [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) route and ended up with a similar, but shorter, solution:

```
>> a = {'(q0, q1)' '(q0, q1)' '(q2, q3)' '(q1, q0)' '(q4, q5)' '(q12, q3)'};
>> [~, index] = unique(sort(cell2mat(textscan([a{:}], '(q%f, q%f)')), 2), 'rows', 'stable');
>> b = a(index)

b =

  1×4 cell array

    '(q0, q1)'    '(q2, q3)'    '(q4, q5)'    '(q12, q3)'
```

Answer (score 3):

So, here is my suggestion:

```
% Input
a = {'(q0, q1)' '(q0, q1)' '(q2, q3)' '(q1, q0)' '(q4, q5)' '(q12, q3)'}

% Omit duplicates
A = unique(a);

% Save for later indexing
AA = A;

% Length of unique-fied input
n = length(A);

% Get x of qx by regular expression -> cell array of cell arrays
A = regexp(A, '\d*', 'match');

% Outer cell array to array + reshape for nicer indexing
A = reshape(cell2mat(A), 2, n);

% Convert char to num for all cell elements -> array
A = cellfun (@(x) str2num(x), A);

% Sort indices for each tuple, i.e. (q1, q0) -> (q0, q1)
A = sort(A)';

% Omit duplicates
[~, I] = unique(A, 'rows');

% Output
b = AA(I)
```

This results in:

```
a =
{
  [1,1] = (q0, q1)
  [1,2] = (q0, q1)
  [1,3] = (q2, q3)
  [1,4] = (q1, q0)
  [1,5] = (q4, q5)
  [1,6] = (q12, q3)
}

b =
{
  [1,1] = (q1, q0)
  [1,2] = (q2, q3)
  [1,3] = (q12, q3)
  [1,4] = (q4, q5)
}
```

And, since you're all loving one-liners ;-) :

```
a = {'(q0, q1)' '(q0, q1)' '(q2, q3)' '(q1, q0)' '(q4, q5)' '(q12, q3)'}
[~, ind] = unique(sort(cellfun (@(x) str2num(x), reshape(cell2mat(regexp(a, '\d*', 'match')), 2, length(a))))', 'rows');
b = a(ind)
```